# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame .Surface, not button

Tags: python, pygame

so i was runing my code and then the new pygame update broke it all and it cant run any images can anyone help me fix this here is the code if needed whenever i run it it just says i hid the import because i didnt have enough space.
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame .Surface, not button. there is some other stuff if you need it just tell me and i will add it

```
class Button():
    def __init__(self, x, y, image, scale):
        width = image.get_width()
        height = image.get_height()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), int(height * scale)))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)
        self.clicked = False

    def draw(self, surface):
        action = False
        #get mouse position
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        #check mouseover and clicked conditions
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                self.clicked = True
                action = True

        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
            self.clicked = False

        #draw button on screen
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

        return action
shoot = Button(100, 200, shoot_img, 0.8)
load = Button(300, 220, load_img, 0.7)
bloc = Button(450, 230, bloc_img, 0.6)
start = Button(100, 200, start_img, 1)

run = True
win = True
y = True
screen.blit(shoot)
while run:
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.update()
     if win == True:
        y = True
        screen.blit(welcome, welcome2)
        screen.blit(name, (200, 50))
        screen.blit(start, (200, 40))
        if start.draw(screen):
            win = False
    if win != True:
        if y == True:
            screen.blit(ammop3, testRect3)
            screen.blit(ammop2, testRect2)
            screen.blit(ammop1, testRect)
            screen.blit(text, textRect)
```

Comment: WHERE do you see that error?  Which line?  You never call your `Button` class here.

Comment: sorry this is my first time using it so i didnt know whats needed

Comment: also the error is the if win == true

Comment: it starts there when the start gets blited

Comment: So the error is in `start.draw(screen)`.  I'm not sure what you expected that to do, but it's not correct.  Did you want to wait for the button to be pressed?

Comment: yes that is what i wanted it to do

Comment: the error is in screen.blit(start)

Comment: Ah, so the error is actually in `screen.blit(shoot)`, right?  You're passing your custom object to the Pygame screen.  It doesn't know how to blit that.  As you said, you should probably do `shoot.draw(screen)`, since the Button knows how to draw itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very self-explanatory. You are trying to blit a button class, when only pictures are supported for blitting. You already have a function for drawing the button on the Button class. Try calling it instead.

```
y = True
shoot.draw(screen)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to blit the image not the class

Comment: He's not blitting the class.  Where did you see that?